# Make my website compatible with internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm trying to get my website compatible with internet explorer. It looks great in chrome, safari and firefox, but i's very wrong in IE.

Is there any way to make it compatible, without changing or creating another css ?

Comment: I’d suggest you make your website [compatible to HTML](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.new-rep-promo-codes.com%2F) first.

Comment: I'd suggest making an attempt at identifying the problem points at hand, and listing what you've tried to do to fix them. As it stands "here's my site help me fix: link" is not the way to ask a question. FYI

Comment: Firstly, when asking IE-related questions, please always specify the IE version(s) you're testing; there are big differences between each IE version. Secondly, please give more detail about the actual problem; what about it doesn't work?

Comment: i'm testing it with windows 8, so i'm guessing it's the latest version. Secondly, when i open it, all of the site's layout appears wrong. the boxes appear when they're not supposed to, so do the images.

Comment: If you're on Win8, you'll have IE10. If you've upgraded to Win8.1, you'll have IE11.

Answer (score 3):

search for IE style sheet. You have to tweek it a little with the elements that you need to change for IE in the new stylesheet. [Read up here about it](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Put this within the `<head>` `tag` of your file

`<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->`

Another that I like to use is `javascript` to use the same stylesheet but uses `css` selectors like. `.ie .container` for internet explorer

you can download it here it's called [CSS Browser Selector](http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/)

Comment: So basically i have to create a css file in order to be able to view my website in IE

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to in most cases, unless you're supporting very old IE versions. But you haven't specified which versions, so.....????

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your code (before you edited out the link from the question), and the first thing that jumps out is that you've got two `X-UA-Compatible` tags, one saying `IE=8` and the other saying `IE=edge`

You should only ever have one of these tags, and in most cases it should only ever be `edge`.

Get rid of the other one; it is causing problems.